# Angular Material Table with expandable rows background color while expanded

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How do I change the background color of the row while it is expanded, then return the color back to normal once it is no longer expanded? The CSS given by the Angular Material example shows how to color during "hover" and "active" but not while it is expanded.

```
tr.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

tr.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):active {
  background: #efefef;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the background-color of the row (not the expanded detail part) when it is expanded, you can use the following CSS:

```
.example-expanded-row {
  background: red;
}
```

> If you want to color the expanded part of the row as well, have a look
>   at
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-cs3qnf?file=app/app.component.ts)
>   stackblitz.